# Control may reach end of non-void function error in C++

Tags: c++

I'm following a tutorial on how to make a game in C++ and I'm getting the "Control may reach end of non-void function" error. I know this error is common and many have already asked on how to solve this, but I just don't get how it is possible that I'm getting this error and thus am unable to run it while my teacher has the EXACT same code and seems to be doing just fine.

This is my code :

```
FText GetValidGuess()
{
    EGuessStatus Status = EGuessStatus::Invalid_Status;
    do {
        int32 CurrentTry = BCGame.GetCurrentTry();
        std::cout << "Try " << CurrentTry << ". Enter your guess! : ";
        FText Guess = "";
        getline(std::cin, Guess);

        Status = BCGame.CheckGuessValidity(Guess);
        switch (Status) {
        case EGuessStatus::Wrong_Length:
            std::cout << "Please enter a " << BCGame.GetHiddenWordLength() << " letter word.\n";
            break;
        case EGuessStatus::Not_Lowercase:
            std::cout << "Please enter your guess in lowercase letters.\n";
            break;
        case EGuessStatus::Not_Isogram:
            std::cout << "Please enter an isogram.\n";
            break;
        default:
                return Guess;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } while (Status != EGuessStatus::OK);
}
```

[Here's a screenshot of the code used in the video, which runs just fine and has no errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6Vhn.jpg)

Am I missing something or how is it possible that I am having trouble and my teacher isn't?
I'm sorry if this question has been asked several times already but I can't seem to fix it and the code is the same as in the video...

Comment: After the while loop add `return Guess` and instantiate `FText Guess` outside the do while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a false positive. The compiler only performs a superficial code analysis for this warning, so it ends up telling you that you "may" get a problem.

In fact, that's the same thing I would tell you if I saw this piece of code in a code review before mentally going through the control flow: *"Are you sure this function always returns something?"*

What's confusing the compiler and your fellow human code reviewer is your redundant loop condition. `Status != EGuessStatus::OK` can *never* be false at this point, so why do you put it there anyway? Turn the loop it into something like `for (;;)`, and the warning should go away.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! Just one question : If it is "just" a warning, how come I can't even build/run my game? When i try, it says "Building Failed" and shows me the error again.

Comment: @Deltox: Probably because you are using some compiler option which makes every warning be treated as an error (which is generally a *good* thing because it teaches people to take warnings seriously!).

Comment: Makes sense... Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

The "error" you're getting is (at least with most compillers) only a warning. Whether it causes the compilation to be aborted can be enabled/disabled using compiler options (usually called "threat warnings as errors"). This may be why you get the error while your teacher does not.

The reason for the error though, is that you don't have a `return` statement at the end of your method. So if Status == EGuessStatus::OK, the method returns an undefined value at the end.

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain why the `default` label in the `switch` statement isn't reached when `Status` becomes `EGuessStatus::OK` and/or why that doesn't make the warning go away.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Good point. The compiler sometimes is unable to determine which values a variable actually can have from the control flow. In this particular example, one could as well just write 'while (true)'.

Comment: @PMF • although I realize you meant to type "treat warnings as errors", I found your typo to be both funny and appropriate.

Comment: @Eljay: Lol, I knew I should have consulted the dictionary, as I was unsure about the spelling :-)

Answer (score 0):

Expected return type is FText, and is not guaranteed if do-while does nothing.

So keep your code fool proof to provide return value always.

In GCC  [-Wreturn-type](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) compiler option can be used to highlight this error.

Cross check the compiler options for [cl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy.aspx)

Comment: There *is* always a return value here if the function is not exited via an exception. I don't see any way the `while` loop could be exited regularly via the loop condition.

Comment: True , i can see return Guess must atleast be "". Exit logic of While loop depends on CheckGuessValidity () when if it returns something other than OK and is not handled in the switch.